# Should the end goal be happiness?

Tags: metaphysics

Should the end goal/telos be happiness? If so, the why not just pump ourselves with dopamine, similar to Brave New World’s “soma”

Comment: According to whom? Different philosophers have said different things on that.

Comment: I’m not sure @Klöcking, I guess I will take any answer. Maybe the most widely accepted, if there is such a thing.

Comment: Does [this answer to another question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/649/17209) address your question? It seems to be about whether happiness as such doesn't seem to lack something.

Comment: Because the sort of "happiness" we aspire to is something far more refined than what dopamine can deliver, see [SEP, Happiness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/happiness/).

Comment: The end goal is satisfaction.

Comment: as @Conifold said happiness is usually meant to not be mere hedonism. you could think of it as it appears in the Tractatus (emphasis mine) "The **world** of the happy is different" (maybe a paraphrase by me)

Comment: Pumping yourself up with dopamine or Soma is a sure way to feel happy, but not a very reliable one. In the end, your supply is gonna lack, and your furnishers will have you in the palm of their hand. Wise people gather knowledge in order to find a way to construct a steady supply of joy. See Spinoza's Ethics on the importance of knowledge for a steady, sustainable life full of joy.

Comment: Happiness Is Not The Meaning Of Life, by Alan Watts, provides a strong case to answer this: https://youtu.be/RsdoJ9x8IBs You can find many threads here that are relevant like https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76956/is-the-foundation-of-morality-subjectively-survival-and-happiness-and-why-or-wh/76980#76980 or https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48684/why-is-everyone-seeking-satisfaction/48691#48691 or https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60770/the-illogical-nature-of-want-motivation-and-its-effects-on-free-will/65655#65655

Answer (score 1):

For some one like Faraday, one's end goal clearly is not happiness, or not even eudaimonia or ataraxia pursued by many philosophers which are much more conservative than happiness. Faraday once famously said: "The strong prove, the weak enjoy"...

As a more deeper explanation as for why happiness should not be one's end goal, if you adopt idealism it might be a little easier to understand. The most powerful foe or perhaps the only foe according to this philosophy is the mindset of yourself. Since nobody is perfect right after birth, so as long as you haven't realized and conquered yourself, you still haven't born-again, and you won't be happy or satisfied at the end of your life. How to realize and conquer yourself? Simply enjoying any happiness via outside material means or pills without your own struggle and effort cannot help. There exists another kind of mutated happiness which is not primitive happiness through normal sense organs, it's a kind of refined "philosophized" happiness full of hybrid forms of both normal senses and your distilled struggled validated epistemologies. This is a new refined mindset full of evolved senses like a final pure gold ring, your original primitive mind is like the raw gold sand. Of course it's easy to describe outside of one's mind, but extremely hard and complicated to realize within one's mind...